# Rational points on ramified coverings of abelian varieties

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, arithmetic-geometry, rational-points

Let $K$ be a number field $A$ an abelian variety over $K$ and $f: X \to A$ a possibly ramified covering of degree $d$ with $X$ a proper variety. My question is:

> Suppose that $f(X(K)) \neq A(K)$, can ond then always find a finite set of strict subgroups $H_1,\ldots, H_n \subsetneq A(K)$ and a sequence of points $x_1, \ldots, x_n$ such that $f(X(K)) \subseteq \bigcup x_i + H_i \neq A(K)$?

This question is only interesting when $\# A(K) = \infty$. And the general result also easily follows from the case where $X$ is irreducible.

Now there are two cases in which I know the answer to be positive:

1. When $A$ is an elliptic curve. Because in the case $X$ is normal if $X(K) \neq \emptyset$ then either $X$ is an elliptic curve as well in which case $f(X(K))$ is already a coset of a finite index subgroup, or $X$ has genus > 1 in which case $X(K)$ is finite and the statement is trivially true. The general case follows from the normal case, cause $X$ has only finitely many singular points.
2. $X$ is a subvariety of an abelian variety $B$. Because in this case one can use a result of Faltings theorem to cover the rational points of $X$ by translates of abelian subvarieties of $B$, and the result follows as well.

I personally even have no idea what I should expect the answer to be. Although I am hoping for a positive answer because of some applications I have for this statement.

Comment: Are you assuming $X$ to  be normal? (When $A$ is an elliptic curve, $X$ could be a singular curve whose normalization is an elliptic curve.)

Comment: If $X$ is normal, and $X\to A$ is a finite surjective not-unramified (i.e., not etale) morphism, then we expect $X(K)$ to be non-dense. (Indeed, such a variety $X$ dominates a positive-dimensional variety of general type by a theorem of Kawamata proven in his PhD thesis, and Lang conjectured non-density of rational points on varieties of general type.) Does this non-density imply what you want?

Comment: Are you assuming that the subgroups $H_1,\dots H_n$ are distinct? Otherwise the conclusion seems to be vacuous: we can take $H_1=\dots =H_n=H$ for $H$ of finite index and let $x_1,\dots, x_n$ be a set of coset representatives of $H\subset A(K)$

Comment: Hi @AriyanJavanpeykar, Indeed I was a bit sloppy with the elliptic curve argument. However, when $X$ is a curve it will have finitely many singular points anyway, so one could cover the rational singular points by cosets of the subgroup {0}. Anyway I would happily accept any answer that gives an answer in the case that $X$ is normal.

Comment: @SashaP thanks for your comment. There was indeed a mistake in my formulation. I do not necessarily require the subgroups to be distinct, however I do require that the union of all the cosets is not equal to $A(K)$. I guess an equivalent formulation would be that I want there to be a non empty coset to be contained in $A(K) \setminus f(X(K))$.

Comment: If $A(K)$ is dense, then $A(K)\setminus f(X(K))$ contains a finite index coset of $A(K)$ by Thm 1.3 in https://arxiv.org/abs/2011.12840 

To deal with the case that $A(K)$ infinite, you can maybe take the closure of $A(K$) and restrict your covering to some well-chosen positive-dimensional component of $\overline{A(K)}$ (which,  by Faltings, is the translate of an abelian subvariety).

Comment: Hi Ariyan,

Thanks for the reference. I think Thm 1.3 should indeed be enough to answer this question in an affirmative way. There is some work to be done to go from that statement to the statement that I am after. But it shouldn't be to hard.